# Bad base path when browser refreshes, ngView breaks

Tags: angularjs

When I access my page from the index and start browsing everything works fine, but when I am on a route other than `/` for example in `/details/123` and I refresh the page(I have URL rewriting configured) the route is not properly set.
It means, when I check the location path when browsing normally from the index and I am on `/details/123` the location path is `/details/123` as expected but when I refresh the page and I am still on `/details/123` the location path changes to `/123` causing ngView to display the wrong view.
I am using html5 mode and Angular v.1.1.5

**UPDATE:** I created a simple example [here](http://routing-test.herokuapp.com/) to illustrate the problem.
I don't have any special setup, I don't think is a server issue. I have the same problem with a different app in python where the redirection is done inside the application.
The `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)       /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: If you set no base href and the real base of your application were "/" I think 1.1.5 would work.. Perhaps you have your server setting the base href to the current page on each rewrite?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This may be related to a nasty issue that showed up during Angular 1.1.5 and is a bug in the core library. A solution that has worked for many is to add the following tag to your index.html head.

If your application is running at the root of your domain.

```
<head>
  ...
  <base href="/"></base>
  ...
</head>
```

Or if your application is running in a subdirectory, specify that subdirectory (e.g. 'myapp'):

```
<head>
  ...
  <base href="/myapp/"></base>
  ...
</head>
```

Additionally, you may also try a new set of rewrite rules. This configuration has worked for many ui-router users.

```xml
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  # Don't rewrite files or directories
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
  RewriteRule ^ - [L]

  # Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
  RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Sounds right to me, from the demo it is clearly defaulting to the current path and it looks like it was fixed after 1.1.5 in: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/aef098006302689d2d75673be828e31903ee7c3c

Comment: Thanks, I'll use this for now. One problem is that this breaks the anchor links.

Comment: how can I solve this issue if I also have a folder with the same name as the link? the Apache enters the sub-directory instead of redirecting into index.html.